# Connect to nodes in a timeline between a start and end point

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a Needham time tree (http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) going down to the hour. 
On each hour node I stored the epoch time

```
CREATE (h:Hour {hour: hour, day:day, month: month, year:year, time: apoc.date.parse(year +"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":00", "s", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")})
```

Now I want to link every hour between the start and end time on my event node.
Something along the lines of

```
create (e:Event {startHour: <some unix time>, endHour: <some later unix time>})
with e
match (h:Hour) 
FOREACH (hour in range(startHour, endHour) |
    merge (e)-[:IN_HOUR]->(h))
```

Obviously that won't work because startHour and endTime are epoch times, not an actual hour.

I do have the hours in the time tree connected with `[:NEXT]` relationships. Could I use that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Your can do this:

```
CREATE (e:Event {startHour: <some unix time>, endHour: <some later unix time>})
WITH e
MATCH (h:Hour)
USING INDEX h:Hour(time)
WHERE e.startHour <= h.time <= e.endHour
MERGE (e)-[:IN_HOUR]->(h);
```

The `USING INDEX` clause gives the Cypher planner a hint that it should use the index (which I assume you already have, for `:Hour(time)`).

[EDITED]

This will work even if `startHour` and `endHour` are not really on an hour. However, if you want `startHour` to be treated as if it were rounded down to the hour, the `WHERE` clause can use `e.startHour/3600*3600` in place of just `e.startHour`.

Comment: Do you know why I'd get this error: (I'm on 3.3.3 enterprise)
Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Failed to fulfil the hints of the query. Could not solve these hints: `USING INDEX h:Hour(time)...

Comment: Did you [create an index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) on `:Hour(time)`, and is `h` indeed the variable name you used in your `MATCH`?

Comment: yes to both. Tried removing the `USING INDEX` clause too. It runs but not sure it it works. it runs VERY slowly.

On the real query I'm not creating a node. I'm matching two existing nodes:
`match (e:Events) match (h:Hour) USING INDEX h:Hour(time)....`

Comment: Are you able to take advantage of indexing on the `MATCH (e:Event)` clause? If you have a lot of `Event` nodes, you would want to avoid having to scan through all of them to find the one you want. You may want to update your question so that it shows what you are actually trying.

Comment: I've tried all the combinations. That's the query I'm using is as follows: `MATCH (e:VisitLocation) MATCH (h:Hour) 
USING INDEX h:Hour(time)
WHERE e.startHour <= h.time <= e.endHour
merge(e)-[:During]->(h)`

It's the same except I call `Event` `VisitLocation`